# Failed to Compile Unknown word error from CSS Minimizer plugin on React build

Tags: reactjs, deployment, npm-build

Failed to compile.

static/css/main.f4eef0d9.css from Css Minimizer plugin
E:\Web Development\MY New Projects\mediclient-frontend\static\css\main.f4eef0d9.css:1460:44: Unknown word [webpack://./src/style.css:3,0][static/css/main.f4eef0d9.css:1460,44]

Ihad one of my (className={`${ isOpen && "bg-primaryColor text-white " } w-7 h-7 lg:w-8 lg:h-8 text-[20px] border border-solid border-[#141F21] rounded flex items-center justify-center`}) like this is there any problem to run build

In localhost my site working proper but not able to deploy